# Microsoft Bot Framework and Slack Direct Messaging - Bots Cannot Message Users in External Teams?

Tags: c#, botframework, slack-api

Following this post, [Microsoft Botframework: Direct Conversation with Bot Channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49737956/microsoft-botframework-direct-conversation-with-bot-channel), I implemented this code into my own bot, getting the error "Bots Cannot Message Users in External Teams". What does this mean and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here's what I did. I went back through Slack and resaved all the settings, and then it worked!. Also, make sure the workspace IDs match for your bot and who you're sending the message to.